# Facing issue with ODataSource Connection Manager in SSIS for pulling the data from Sharepoint site

Tags: sql, authentication, sharepoint, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

We are trying to pull data from Sharepoint site using SSIS ODataSource Connection Manager. But, we are facing issue with the ODataSource which is failing when we are trying to test the connection. It is giving below error message, even though the password we are giving is correct. We are using Microsoft Online Services as Authentication Type.

### TITLE: OData Connection Manager Editor

### Test connection failed

> The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft
>   account system.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.ODataConnectionManager)

We are using SSDT Version 2017. Here is the screenshot for your reference.

Can you please let us know, what would be the issue and how to fix this.

Thanks in Advance!!

[image]

Comment: Have you verified that you are able to access the sharepoint site using those credentials some other way?  Seems to indicate an issue with the password, maybe it expired and needs to be reset.

Comment: Hi @TimMylott, password is not expired. I have tried with my credentials. Still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: We had the same problem. It seems to be something to do with multi-factor authentication (that's about all we know on the cause). As for fixing it, using app passwords didn't help, but turning off MFA for that user sorted everything out for us.